# What module can strip debugs in webpack solutions?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack

I am running a reactjs app with gulp/webpack and tried this:
https://github.com/yahoo/strip-loader. 
However it does not work( throws errors in my reactjs code). How to get it working or what is another solution?

EDIT
I added this to the loaders section of the webpack.config:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    drop_debug: true
})
```

I have installed the plugin with npm but it does not filter the debugger statements from my reactjs code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UglifyJsPlugin() and pass the `drop_debugger: true` property.

To utilize this property you need to pass it to the `compress` property inside of the options argument.

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(
  compressor: {
    drop_debugger: true
  }
);
```

This is an UglifyJS specific property and webpack can pass those directly through `compress`. Ironically looking at the source of the plugin it can also take the property `compressor` as an alt property.

Comment: Now I get :`drop_debug` is not a supported option?

Comment: Sorry I updated one more time. the answer. Let me know if this is still an issue,

Answer (score 0):

you can use strip-loader plugin in webpack.

```
var WebpackStripLoader = require('strip-loader');
WebpackStripLoader.loader('console.log', 'console.error', 'debugger')
```